# Rake Assets:Precompile error pushing rails app to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I'm gonna start by saying I hate heroku with a passion right now.

Okay, onto it. I'm pushing an app to heroku, and getting the "precompiling assets failed" error. I've tried about 100 things to fix it, and nothing works. I've tried setting

```
    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

In my application.rb file, doesn't work. I've tried precompiling locally, comiting and pushing, as well as hiding locally precompiled assets. I've tried pushing in different environments as well.

Here is my error log, where things start to happen:

```
> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   rake aborted!
   SyntaxError: (erb):82: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
   (erb):85: unterminated string meets end of file
   /tmp/build_1843337b33065f83ff572061af54f827/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mongoid-4.0.0/lib/mongoid/config/environment.rb:40:in `load_yaml'
   /tmp/build_1843337b33065f83ff572061af54f827/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mongoid-4.0.0/lib/mongoid/config.rb:83:in `load!'
   /tmp/build_1843337b33065f83ff572061af54f827/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mongoid-4.0.0/lib/mongoid.rb:99:in `load!'
   /tmp/build_1843337b33065f83ff572061af54f827/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mongoid-4.0.0/lib/mongoid/railtie.rb:75:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
   /tmp/build_1843337b33065f83ff572061af54f827/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
   /tmp/build_1843337b33065f83ff572061af54f827/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
   /tmp/build_1843337b33065f83ff572061af54f827/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
   /tmp/build_1843337b33065f83ff572061af54f827/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
   /tmp/build_1843337b33065f83ff572061af54f827/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
   /tmp/build_1843337b33065f83ff572061af54f827/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_1843337b33065f83ff572061af54f827/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
   /tmp/build_1843337b33065f83ff572061af54f827/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
   /tmp/build_1843337b33065f83ff572061af54f827/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
   /tmp/build_1843337b33065f83ff572061af54f827/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
   /tmp/build_1843337b33065f83ff572061af54f827/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:276:in `require_environment!'
   /tmp/build_1843337b33065f83ff572061af54f827/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:389:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
   /tmp/build_1843337b33065f83ff572061af54f827/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in define'
   Tasks: TOP => environment
```

I see the "syntax error" near the top, but I have no idea which file to look in. 
Can anyone help me out?

Here's the end of my mongoid.yml file, from lines 78 to 90

```
78    staging:
79      sessions:
80        default:
81          database: <dbname>
82          hosts: 
83           - <host>:<port>
84          username: <username> 
85          password: <password> 
86        options:
87    production:
88      sessions:
89        default:
90          uri: <%= ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] %>
```

Comment: Paste the content of the mongoid.yml file. There is a syntax error on it.

Comment: Okay I added it. Is it always going to be in the mongoid.yml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first few lines of the stacktrace point you to the problem:

```
Running: rake assets:precompile
rake aborted!
SyntaxError: (erb):82: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
(erb):85: unterminated string meets end of file
/tmp/build_1843337b33065f83ff572061af54f827/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mongoid-4.0.0/lib/mongoid/config/environment.rb:40:in `load_yaml'
```

The error occured when Mongoid tried to load its YAML config, `mongoid.yml`.

## Finding the problem

**This has nothing to do with Heroku.** The line of `mongoid.yml` mentioned in the stacktrace points to the `staging` part, and you should be able to reproduce the error locally by running:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=staging
```

BTW, are you still running Rails 3? Because [according to Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline):

> In Rails 4.x this option [`initialize_on_precompile`] has been removed and is no longer needed.

## The solution

My guess is you need to quote strings containing colons. It should be:

```
78    staging:
79      sessions:
80        default:
81          database: <dbname>
82          hosts: 
83           - '<host>:<port>'
84          username: <username> 
85          password: <password> 
86        options:
87    production:
88      sessions:
89        default:
90          uri: <%= ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] %>
```

not `- <host>:<port>` (notice the single quotes above).

Comment: I'm running Rails 4.1. Btw it wasn't the quotes, it was the "options" (line 86) that should have been indented to line up with "password". Thank you for your help! I spent a few hours trying about 100 different things, and I wouldn't have caught it otherwise! A++

Comment: I'm glad you could make it work, even though the answer only pointed in the right direction.